# Python Code wont Run giving unnecessary TypeError, not sure why?

Tags: python, typeerror, factory, python-3.5

I'm learning python and finally got around to playing with factories. The code below is giving me the following error and I don't know why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py_Lab\Factory.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(MyFactory("Ham").x)
  File "C:\py_Lab\Factory.py", line 30, in MyFactory
    if cls.Check(myStr):
TypeError: Check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'myStr'
```

The factory definition is suppose to loop through the sub-classes of the base classes and use the `Check()` definition in the sub-classes to choose which class to run. I'm pretty sure the parameter `'myStr'` is where it should be, and I have placed an argument in the instance of the factory. Is this error due to the way python compiles or something? I'm running `python 3.5` on a `Windows 8` pc.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    pass

class AltBaseClass(object):
    pass

class C1(BaseClass, AltBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = 1
    def Check(self, myStr, *args, **kwargs):
        return myStr == "Ham"

class C2(BaseClass, AltBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = 30
    def Check(self, myStr, *args, **kwargs):
        return myStr == "Sandwich"

class C3(BaseClass, AltBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = 70
    def Check(self, myStr, *args, **kwargs):
        return myStr == "Pancake"

def MyFactory(myStr):
    for cls in BaseClass.__subclasses__():
        if cls.Check(myStr):
            return cls()

def OthrFactory(myStr):
    for cls in AltBaseClass.__subclasses__():
        if cls.Check(myStr):
            return cls()

print(MyFactory("Ham").x)
print(OthrFactory("Sandwich").x)
print(OthrFactory("Pancake").x)
```

Comment: You've written `Check` as an instance method, but you don't have an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Check()` static with the `@staticmethod` decorator. Maybe a [`@classmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) could be usefull too.

```
@staticmethod
def Check(myStr, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    pass
```

This way you do not have a `self` (an instance) which `myStr` got interpreted as.

Answer (score 0):

When running `Check()` at `cls.Check(myStr)`, you missed an argument. `Check(self, myStr, *args, **kwargs)` requires 2 arguments, `self` and `myStr`. Therefore, running `Check(myStr)` needs a second argument, which, by name, I assume is `self`.